# Order E-Mail: How to exchange SKU with other Attribute?

Tags: email-templates, ce-1.9.1.0

i will display another Attribute (manufacturer_sku) in the Order- E-Mail instead of the shop sku.

Found the Code here:

```
app/design/frontend/base/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

$this->escapeHtml($this->getSku($_item))
```

How can i change the SKU with my attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is not save  `manufacturer_sku attribute` values at sales_flat_order_item,so you cannot get   manufacturer_sku attribute value `without load product` by order item productid .

So do this.

```
   $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
if($_product->getId()){
echo $_product->getData('manufacturer_sku ')
}
```